# How to tell if react is used in a webapp?

Tags: reactjs

In a webapp with javascript minified, is there a way to tell if a webapp uses reactjs using developer console?

Comment: You can use the React Developer Tools extenstion and it will tell you if the page is using React

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check by just using typeof:

```
typeof React
```

But this will only verify on the page you're currently on. Nowadays, app consists of multiple environments, frameworks, etc. You may use some extension that will tell you what framework is being used in the application. For eg. check builtWith.

Comment: doesn't work for a simple react app created by `npx create-react-app my-app`